# Accessing an element's parentNode, if the element has a child named parentNode

Tags: javascript, dom

This is sort of a pathological case, but say I have the following HTML:

```
<div data-whatever="somevalue">
  <form id="identifier">
    <input name="parentNode">
    <input name="parentElement">
    [...]
  </form>
</div>
```

And I have a reference to the form, e.g.

```
var form = document.getElementById('identifier');
```

I would like to read the form's parent's `data-whatever` attribute. However. I can't simply do

```
form.parentNode.getAttribute('data-whatever');
```

because `form.parentNode` will return the `input` tag. How do I navigate up to the form's parent node, given potential child nodes whose names are `parentNode`, `parentElement`, etc?

**Edit:** to clarify, I need to navigate the DOM of HTML that I cannot control, hence the weirdness.

Comment: The cop out answer would be don't do that. :P

Comment: Hah I agree! My situation is that I'm working in a scenario where I have no control over the HTML that my Javascript needs to process :(

Comment: Why is the parentNode of a form an input tag? That can't be legal.

Comment: You can give whatever names you like to your input elements. Well, that's not strictly true, but it's certainly not illegal to name your input "parentNode"

Comment: Oh I see, you need to harm your HTML writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you effectively want to do is to bypass a method override of the prototype hierarchy of the DOM node.

I.e. calling a superclass method.

This can be achieved as follows:

```
let parentNodeGetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Node.prototype, "parentNode").get;
parentNodeGetter.apply(form)
```

Works in firefox at least.

Comment: This looks like exactly the general solution I'd like. Sadly Chrome seems to barf on the "let" :( Thank you though, this approach is very interesting

Comment: Actually, it looks like I can do without the let. This looks like exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: ah yeah, that's es6 syntax

Answer (score 4):

Use [**parentElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

```js
var form = document.getElementById('identifier');

var parent = form.parentElement;
var attribute = parent.getAttribute('data-whatever');

console.log(attribute);
```

```html
<div data-whatever="somevalue">
  <form id="identifier">
    <input name="parentNode">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you cannot depend on `parentElement`, do it manually using a top-down approach

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-whatever]');
var attribute = '';
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].contains(document.getElementById('identifier'))) {
    attribute = elements[i].getAttribute('data-whatever');
    break;
  }
}
console.log(attribute);
```

```html
<div data-whatever="somevalue">
  <form id="identifier">
    <input name="parentNode">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice, and answers my question as originally stated. However I'm looking for something more general, since I'm operating on HTML that I cannot control. (e.g. what if I have an input named parentElement as well?) I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Interesting idea! I suppose I can do the normal parentNode, check to see if its name is parentNode, and if so, drill downwards instead. Thanks :)

Comment: Although for the downward drilling, I will need to check if it's an immediate child, rather than a descendant like `contains` checks. Still, thank you for the direction!